# DataMapper delete works but only after restarting my app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have two models, User and Snippet:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,Serial
  ...
  has n,:snippets
end

class Snippet
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,Serial
  ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I'm displaying the snippets, I'm using this:

```
snippets = user.snippets
```

And when I'm deleting them I'm using this:

```
snippet = Snippet.first(:user_id => user.id,:id => snip_id)
if snippet
    destruction_res = snippet.destroy
    ...
end
```

The thing is, destruction_res always returns true. I tried saving the user after I deleted the snippet. It returned true as well. The thing is, when I access the view that uses the code:

```
snippets = user.snippets
```

it returns the complete list, including the snippet which should have been destroyed. If I restart the application however, I see the correct list. What am I doing wrong? Should I somehow force a commit to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you're loading the snippets collection before destroying a snippet then you access that collection again and it still includes the deleted snippet. If that's the case, you can reject a destroyed snippet like that:

```
user.snippets.reject!(&:destroyed?)
```

BTW - you can destroy a snippet like this:

```
user.snippets.get(snip_id).destroy
```

A bit nicer :)

Comment: Yes, I had the collection in memory, and this was the silent bug. I rewrote it and now it works ok, but still, I would have expected that the objects were "better tied" to the database. Lesson learned, don't make assumptions :)